# Hopping to infinity along a string of digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, turing-machines

Let $s$ be an infinite string of decimal digits, for example:
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 s = 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 & \cdots
\end{array}
Consider a marker, the *head*, pointing to the first digit, $3$ in the above example. Interpret the digit under
the head as an instruction to move the head $3$ digits to the right, i.e., to the $4$th digit. Now the head is pointing to $1$. Interpret this as an instruction to move $1$ place to the left. Continue in this manner, hopping through the string, alternately moving right and left. Think of the head as akin to the head of a Turing machine, and $s$ as the tape of instructions.

There are three possible behaviors.
(1) The head moves off the left end of $s$:

---

\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{}
\end{array}

---

(2) The head goes into a cycle, e.g., when the head hits $0$:

---

\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} 
\end{array}

---

(3) The head moves off rightward to infnity:

---

\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{ ${}^{\wedge}$} & \text{} \\
\end{array}

---

This last string could be viewed as the decimal expansion of $31/99 = 0.3131313131313\cdots$.

> ***Q1***. What is an example of an irrational number
>   $0.d_1 d_2 d_3 \cdots$ whose string $s=d_1 d_2 d_3 \cdots$ causes the head to hop rightward to infinity?
>
> ***Q1.5***. (*Added*). Is there an explicit irrational algebraic number with the hop-to-$\infty$ property?

I'm thinking of something like $\sqrt{7}-2$, the 
2nd example above (which cycles).

> ***Q2***. More generally, which strings
>   cause the head to hop rightward to infinity?

---

*Update* (summarizing answers, 13Apr2019).
***Q1***. There are irrationals with the hop-to-$\infty$ property
(@EthanBolker, @TheSimpliFire),
but explicit construction requires using, e.g., the 
Thue-Morse sequence (@Wojowu).
***Q1.5***. @EthanBolker suggests this may be difficult, and @Wojowu suggests it may be false (b/c: nine consecutive zeros): Perhaps no algebraic irrational has the hop-to-$\infty$ property.
***Q2***. A partial algorithmic characterization by @TheSimpliFire.

Comment: You want a string such that the $D_1=(1+d_1)$th digit is less than $d_1$, that the $D_2=(1+d_1-D_1)$th digit is greater than $D_1$, that the $D_3=(1+d_1-D_1+D_2)$th digit is less than $D_2$, etc. I think it is possible to generate an algorithm and you can try for some simulations.

Comment: Another question. For sequences that don't hop to infinity behavior is determined by a (finite) initial subsequence. There are only countably many of those. What are they?

Comment: I think Q1.5 is  hard since digit sequences for algebraic numbers are hard http://adamczewski.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Siauliai.pdf

Comment: Followup question: what are the measures of the three sets in the interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog The set of numbers with hop to infinity property has measure zero, because you can't hop past a string of nine zeros. This also strongly suggests no algebraic irrational has this property.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Also, there are at least as many type $2$ sequences as type $1$ sequences -- just take the last digit (before jumping off the left edge) and replace it with $0$.  I would guess there are many more type $2$ than type $1$, actually.

Comment: @antkam I don't think your reasoning works: you are replacing many type 1 sequences with one type 2 sequence, for instance, you would replace $12,\dots,19$ with $10$ - eight type 1 sequences vs one type 1 sequence.

Comment: @Wojowu - you are right...  i wrote that late at night and realized my mistake after sleeping. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$
x 1^{x-2} y 1^{y-2} z1^{z-2} \ldots
$$
moves off to infinity for any sequence of digits $xyz\ldots$ between $3$ and $9$. Select a sequence that defines an irrational number.

More generally

$$
x 1 ?^{x-1} y 1  ?^{y-1} z 1 ?^{z-1} \ldots
$$
works, where $?^n$ is an arbitrary string of $n$ digits, since those spots will never be hopped on.

Comment: Nice! Could you be more explicit about how you know the resulting digit string is irrational? Thanks.

Comment: Clearly it will be irrational if $t = 0.xyz\ldots$ is, since then periodicity is impossible. It can be even when $t$ is rational because the $?$'s can force that.

Comment: I worry about explicitly specifying $t=0.xyz\cdots$, excluding digits $\{ 0,1,2 \}$, guaranteeing $t$ is irrational.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Take the Thue-Morse sequence, add 3 to each term and take that as a binary sequence. Don't hope for a better sort of answer - our understanding of decimal expansions of "natural" constants is really bad, so you won't be able to exclude 0,1,2 without artificially constructing the decimal expansion.

Comment: Thank you, @Wojowu!